# How do I calculate age using the date format in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, format

I am a beginner. I intend to calculate a persons age and display it on a textfield. What I don't know is:

1. The date format android saves when I enter the date in the app ?
2. How to manipulate this format so I can subtract with the current calender and get the cage ?

Many thanks.

additional info: app is set to accept the date in the text field with the date format.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/dob"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dobtext"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: We're here to help with programming problems, not teach you how to program. "enter the date in the app" is meaningless. you could enter the word "yesterday" into a text field and that would technically qualify as a date.

Comment: The texfield format is set to accept date. This is done in android studio.

Comment: This is a programming problem.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't shown ANY of your programming code. We're happy to help, we're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. You enter person birthday and you want to calculate his age from that date to now? I think you need to write this on google : "how to use date selection in android" .

Comment: I understand that. I will be able to do this easily if i have different fields for thee, day, month, year. I wana know how to do it if I enter the date in one field together. If its possible.

Comment: Did you try date picker? Check it out : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Comment: You are welcome Abdullah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example, String dt="2015-03-06" got from EditText

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar calendar=sdf.parse(dt);
String result=calendar.getDate().toString();
```